# Creating buttons taking value from database and assigning onclick listener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am getting some error in assigning OnclickListener to dynamically created buttons

1. when i call getText function it receives the value of the last created button(clicking on any button).
2. i want to start a new activity by clicking that buttons, but it gives java.lang.nullpointerexception.

here is my code:

```
public void getTableList(LinearLayout layout, String s) {
    Log.e("in getTableList", "in getTableList");
    b = new Button(shuddhContext);
    b.setText(s);
    b.setTextSize(15);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.class_button);
    b.setLayoutParams(params);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                "com.shuddhatm.attendencemonitor.STUDENTLIST");
            String className = b.getText().toString();

            myIntent.putExtra("className", className);
            try{
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(shuddhContext, e.toString() + "\n" + b.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    layout.addView(b);
}
```

the logcat while clicking the button (**with try/catch block**)

```
04-13 23:32:38.561: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5305a000 size:245760
04-13 23:32:38.561: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x50281000 size:4096
04-13 23:32:41.331: E/button Click(7243): step1
04-13 23:32:41.331: E/button Click(7243): step2
04-13 23:32:41.331: E/button Click(7243): step3
04-13 23:32:41.331: E/button Click(7243): step4
04-13 23:32:41.381: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5305a000 size:245760 offset:0 fd:74
04-13 23:32:41.391: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x50281000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:76
04-13 23:32:42.931: E/button Click(7243): step1
04-13 23:32:42.931: E/button Click(7243): step2
04-13 23:32:42.931: E/button Click(7243): step3
04-13 23:32:42.931: E/button Click(7243): step4
04-13 23:32:44.881: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5305a000 size:245760
04-13 23:32:44.881: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x50281000 size:4096
04-13 23:32:44.931: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5305a000 size:245760 offset:0 fd:74
04-13 23:32:44.931: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x50281000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:76
04-13 23:32:48.371: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5305a000 size:245760
04-13 23:32:48.371: D/memalloc(7243): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x50281000 size:4096
```

the logcat while clicking the button (**without try/catch block**):

```
04-13 23:48:50.901: D/memalloc(8869): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x53ef4000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:65
04-13 23:48:50.901: D/memalloc(8869): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4006f000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:68
04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step1
04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step2
04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step3
04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step4
04-13 23:48:50.981: W/dalvikvm(8869): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41275540)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3409)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3580)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3548)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at com.shuddhatm.attendancemonitor.AMData$1.onClick(AMData.java:142)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)<br />
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
04-13 23:48:51.041: E/AndroidRuntime(8869):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please add the log output. in which line it is giving the null point exception? did you do debugging?

Comment: when Starting the activity
startActivity(myIntend)

Comment: can you please post the log output anyways...

Comment: Sure that your intent is normally working? did you try to run the intent in another piece of code?

Comment: @user3345454, Is it your full log? Where is the NullPointerException?

Comment: ya my intent is working normally

Comment: it is handled by try block, i see it in toast created in catch block

Comment: @laymelek, here is the log output

Comment: so you are clicking the button for times and only after that you get the error? 04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step1
04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step2
04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step3
04-13 23:48:50.981: E/button Click(8869): step4

Comment: no actually to check error i put log.e after every line

Comment: Please post your full source code. It displays the text from the previously created button because you're overwriting the button view property with each iteration of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem here is trying to get text of the `Button` clicked, while the `b` variable inside the `onClick` method **cannot** access to it if it's not `final`. To avoid this, you can retrieve the view clicked (because here `b == v`) as follows:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // b == v
    String className = v.getText().toString();
}
```

Another problem might be your `Intent` declaration:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.shuddhatm.attendencemonitor.STUDENTLIST");
```

I guess "*com.shuddhatm...STUDENTLIST*" is the new `Activity`, I'd suggest you to do as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AMData.this, STUDENTLIST.class);
```

[According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent):

> The constructor used here takes two parameters:
>   - A **Context** as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)
>   - The **Class of the app component** to which the system should deliver the Intent (in this case, the activity that should be started)

Then, because `AMData` and `STUDENTLIST` are inside the same package, you could avoid to write the full name of the class.
Finally, make sure that `shuddhContext` return the right context. If not, you should use `AMData.this`. And you can avoid the `try/catch` method for your `Intent`, I think this is useless.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer. This is more or less what I would have suggested, however I would add that the activity should implement OnClickListener so then you can override the listener function in the activity and therefore access the activity properties and methods in a non-static way.

Comment: Yes @tpbapp, it should be a great implementation. However, I don't think it's related to OP's error, but indeed it is the right behaviour to have.

Comment: @Fllo, thanks the first problem is resolved. But Intent is not working with it. i have tested it in other code using a static button and it is working correctly

Comment: @Fllo thanks a lot it worked my mistake, getting the context wrong

Comment: @user3345454 You're welcome. Would you accept my answer please? To help someone who has the same issue. Thank you.